# Excel text split

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

Sample

```
Modified and self-produced (d)

Food packages (d,d,d,d,e,e,d,d,e,d,d)

Other country’s food labels (d)

Using food labels to choose foods for Healthy eating (d)

Measuring cups food models (d)

Food labelling exercise – custom (e) 

Food product promotional pamphlet (d)

It pays to read your grocery label (d)

Old food labels (d)

Self-produced worksheet to help students navigate through reading real packages (e,e)

Products from the kitchen (e)

Grocery store tour – reading labels on foods (d)
```

Essentially I want to split the text between parentheses into separate Excel entries.

Modified and self-produced |||| (d)

Food packages |||| (d,d,d,d,e,e,d,d,e,d,d)

Other country’s food labels |||| (d)

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If the data truly is in parentheses you can use a function to do the split

To get what's in the prarenthes, use in A3 (with your data in A1)

```
A3 =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)+1-FIND("(",A1,1))
```

Then you can get what's left by using in A2

```
A2 =LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(A3))
```

You may also wish place the following around the formulas to clean up extra blank characters.

```
trim()
```

Let me know if this isn't working for you.

Comment: I just figured out how to make that formula work. It took a while to let my of ability making formulas or editing them to be overtaken by my ability to have things happen by luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want each comma-delimited element inside the parentheses to each be on a separate column?

If so, you can do this:

- Paste the data into a blank sheet.
- Replace all of the left- and right-parentheses with commas.
- Select the column that has all the data, and then select Data / Text to Columns.
- Select Delimited, then select Comma as the delimiter.

Comment: I want the data in the parentheses to be moved to a seperate column, or the parentheses and their contents moved to another column. Either way works as long as it's consistent. Essentially take "Food packages (d,d,d,d,e,e,d,d,e,d,d)" on B4 and turn it into "Food packages" on B4 and (d,d,d,d,e,e,d,d,e,d,d) on C4.

Comment: In that case, do the same thing, but use semicolons instead of commas in the second and fourth steps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Data - Text to Column and split on the open paren. You will lose the open paren, however, so it may not be as good an option as the formula.